# Two different forms submit buttons are conflicting on a page

Tags: php, forms, form-submit

I have two forms in my page and both are having ajax function on submitting the form. My problem is  that when I click the submit button of first form then second form automatically starts loading its result and shows error.

What to do to solve this problem?

Here is the screenshot of the two forms:

[image]

Comment: Could you show some code too pls ?

Comment: Where is you code ? with out it we can't help you.